# Should I handle a GraphQL ID as a string on the client?

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js, graphql, apollo

I am building an application using:

- MySQL as the backend database
- Apollo GraphQL server as a query layer for that database
- Sequelize as the ORM layer between GraphQL and MySQL

As I am building out my GraphQL schema I'm using the GraphQL ID data type to uniquely identify records. Here's an example schema and its MySQL resolver/connector

**Graphql Type:**

```
type Person {
  id: ID!
  firstName: String
  middleName: String
  lastName: String
  createdAt: String
  updatedAt: String
}
```

**Sequelize connector**

```
export const Person = sequelize.define('person', {
  firstName: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
  middleName: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
  lastName: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
});
```

**GraphQL resolver:**

```
Query: {
  person(_, args) {
    return Person.findById(args.id);
}
```

So that all works. Here's my question. GraphQL seems to treat the `ID` type as a string. While the ID value gets stored in the MySQL database as an `INT` by Sequelize. I can use GraphQL to query the MySQL db with either a string or a integer that matches the ID value in the database. However, GraphQL will always return the ID value as a string.

How should I be handling this value in the client? Should I always convert it to an integer as soon as I get it from GraphQL? Should I modify my sequelize code to store the ID value as a string? Is there a correct way to proceed when using GraphQL IDs like this?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`ID` is a scalar type described in the [GraphQL specification](http://spec.graphql.org/October2016/#sec-ID) (working draft October 2016):

> The ID type is serialized in the same way as a String; however, it is not intended to be human‐readable. While it is often numeric, it should always serialize as a String.

---

Your observation

> I can use GraphQL to query the MySQL db with either a string or a integer that matches the ID value in the database. However, GraphQL will always return the ID value as a string.

is aligned with the specification about **result coercion**:

> GraphQL is agnostic to ID format, and serializes to string to ensure consistency across many formats ID could represent

and **input coercion**:

> When expected as an input type, any string (such as "4") or integer (such as 4) input value should be coerced to ID as appropriate for the ID formats a given GraphQL server expects

---

**How should I be handling this value in the client?**

- When working with `ID` *results*, treat them as strings.
- When using `ID` *inputs* (in GraphQL variables or input parameters for mutations or queries), you can either use integers or strings.

**Should I always convert it to an integer as soon as I get it from GraphQL?**

That's highly depending on your application. There is no general rule that dictates a clear "yes" or "no" here.

**Should I modify my sequelize code to store the ID value as a string?**

No, that's not required.

The GraphQL specification about the `ID` type does not cover how you *store* the ids, only how a GraphQL server is expected to treat `ID` input and output. It's up to the GraphQL layer to ensure this behaviour. How ids are handled in the actual storage is up to the storage layer.

**Is there a correct way to proceed when using GraphQL IDs like this?**

I hope the above answers also answer this question :)

Comment: This is an excellent explanation of the various considerations around this issue. Thanks. GraphQL offers such an open ended approach to data structures that it can be difficult to figure out the **right** way.

Comment: Can I just use Int instead of ID type for mysql primary columns?  React apollo already allows a custom function 'dataObjectId' to set an object ID. Setting ID scalar type for primary keys doesn't seem to have any benefits.

Comment: What does it mean by `...it is not intended to be human‐readable` ?  Anything is readable as long as the length overexceeds the boundary.

Comment: [human-readable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human-readable_medium) text refers to natural language text that can easily be read and understood by a human familiar with the language used for the text. As opposed to [machine-readable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-readable_data) text, that can be easily processed by a computer. For example, using latin letters for a string is better human-readable than using ASCII codes, which is more machine-readable.

Comment: I'd say use ID datatype only if it's a string. Although GraphQL docs says it's agnostic to datatype it clearly prefers strings. Agnostic would be not touching the datatype.