# How to eliminate quotes on integers in JSON from GraphiQL/Flask/Graphene/SQLAlchemy/PostgreSQL

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, graphene-python, graphene-sqlalchemy

The following JSON has quotes around the integers, and I need these gone (observe the rRegionkey):

```
{
  "data": {
    "regionsAll": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "rComment": "hs use ironic, even requests. s",
            "rName": "AMERICA",
            "rRegionkey": "1"
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "rComment": "ges. thinly even pinto beans ca",
            "rName": "ASIA",
            "rRegionkey": "2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This JSON comes from the following stack, all the latest versions:

- **GraphiQL**.  Within a browser, I hit the usual /graphql end point.
- **Flask**.  As the web app server.
- **Graphene**.  This is the GraphQL library.  Including the graphene_sqlalchemy library.
- **SQLAlchemy**.  Used as the ORM to the database.
- **PostgreSQL**.  As the database.  The region key is an integer as shown below.

Somewhere in this stack, the integer in PostgreSQL turns into a quoted string in the JSON.  Where?  What setting can I set to get rid of the quotes?

Just to confirm, the \d of the table in PostgreSQL is here (observe the type of r_regionkey):

```
   Column    |          Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default
-------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 r_regionkey | integer                |           | not null |
 r_name      | character varying(25)  |           | not null |
 r_comment   | character varying(152) |           |          |
```

At the ORM level, I'm pulling it in as an Integer(observe again r_regionkey):

```
class Region(Base):

    __tablename__  = 'h_region_int'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload': True}

    r_name         = Column(String, doc='The company name for the region.')
    r_regionkey    = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, doc='Identifier for the region.')
    r_comment      = Column(String, doc='Extended information about the region.')
```

As I move into Graphene, I don't mess with the column level at all:

```
class Region(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = RegionModel
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )
        description='A collection of nations around the world.'
```

By the time I'm up to Flask, I'm really just doing sweeping things, not messing with columns:

```
app.add_url_rule(
    "/graphql",
    view_func=GraphQLView.as_view("graphql", schema=schema, graphiql=True)
)
```

So my question--what obscure setting somewhere along the way do I need to set to get those quotes off my integer data types?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47874344/should-i-handle-a-graphql-id-as-a-string-on-the-client

Comment: You nailed it!  Someone with enough reputation can mark this question as duplicate.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: As per request for close as duplicate: [Should I handle a GraphQL ID as a string on the client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47874344/should-i-handle-a-graphql-id-as-a-string-on-the-client)